# Regular Expresions, Is this possible with a regex?

Tags: regex

as indicated above I need help with a complex regular expression, which  I can't figure out (I'm starting to think that it can't be done)
The section to be divided is as follows:

**{FROM                              }{##LIMITE##    }[R]{ TO }{##LIMITE##              }[R]
{##MONEDA##  }{%}**

**There are spaces after "##"**

The following is required:
-That it counts that the section does not exceed 112 characters (spaces includes)
-That within those 112 characters do not count those characters that are between:
**- ##letters / num##

- [R] or [L]
- "{"or"}"
- "[" or "]"
- [%]**

In conclusion, you have to count spaces, letters not included in the expressions above or that are one of those characters.
Any help will be welcome, but I begin to think that you cannot make a single expression that can do all of this at the same time.
Thanks.

Comment: With regex you can match a pattern, but it can't do calculations on it's own. So can we assume you'll be using javascript to count those spaces?

Comment: i can only use regular expresions =(

Comment: _Because regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool._

Comment: Sry, only JS language